# Confusion re COS method and Levy Processes

Tags: option-pricing

In the COS method (http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/mf/users/oosterlee/oosterlee/COS.pdf), they say that

[image]

What do they mean that this holds for "Levy processes"? Surely this holds for all processes?

Here, $x = log(S_0/K)$, and $S_t = S_0 e^{L_t}$, and $\phi(\omega;x)$ is the characteristic function of $\log(S_t/K) = L_t + x$, and so

$$\phi(\omega; x) = E e^{i \omega (L_t + x)} = e^{i \omega x} E^{i \omega L_t} = \phi_{L}(\omega) e^{i\omega x}$$

.... this holds no matter what $L_t$ is, Levy or not. So why do they state it only holds for Levy processes?

Comment: I think it is the independence of increments piece that the Lévy process sets it aside from others. What would the characteristic function look like for a process whose volatility depends on the level of the underlying stock?